# Why does wkwebview run slower in cordova compare to mobile safari?

Tags: ios, cordova, famo.us, wkwebview

I've built an app using famo.us which runs very nicely in the native ios 8 browser and also this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webview-wkwebview-uiwebview/id928647773?mt=8

The app in the link allows you to test the performance in both UIWebView and WKWebView.

I've noticed after profiling in instruments that my app uses about 30-40% more cpu in cordova than when running in the app above.  I have tried using both UIWebView and the experimental WKWebView plugin from Telerik.  I have even tried pointing cordova directly to a webserver with the contents of my app.

No matter what I strip out or try, my app runs considerably slower in cordova.  If cordova and the app store app use the same webviews (presumably), why would the former consume so much more cpu?

Any insight into where the overhead is in cordova would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We've found that adding a (almost hidden) UIToolbar to the cordova project (to the MainController.view) improves performance. Strange but true...

Comment: that is insane. are you allowed to share a github gist of the required files? (xib, view, whatever)?

Comment: Adding the UIToolbar certainly made some difference, but later on we found the real cause, and apparently there was spinning-div somewhere else in the DOM causing the drop in performance.